# What exactly does this sentence mean: " ... typically 10-100 times that of a plain-vanilla email campaign"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "That extra effort is what gives traditional media its added oomph—typically 10-100 times that of a plain-vanilla email campaign"

This sentence is used in below paragraph:

> > They work because, to your prospect, it's a given that you've put in more effort. (A printed sales pack costs you more to put together; a telephone call takes 100% of one person's attention for its duration.) That extra effort is what gives traditional media its added oomph—typically 10-100 times that of a plain-vanilla email campaign.

I think that it means: extra effort can make the media more appealing. But the next part of the sentence is ambiguous  for me:

- *typically 10-100 times that of a plain-vanilla email campaign*

Comment: It doesn't mean the extra cost (not exactly "effort") makes the actual *media* more appealing. It means a *campaign* conducted through traditional media has more "appeal" (however you measure that) than a campaign of *equivalent cost* conducted using email (but not "customised", so effectively the comparison is to a *"**spam** email campaign"*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ***traditional media*** [campaign] (in long-established forms such as radio, television, and newspapers)
*has more **oomph*** (strength, power, [sex] appeal)
*than a **plain-vanilla** email campaign* (standard, basic, without any added features)

It's a pretty vacuous thing to say, since it's almost impossible to measure/quantify the efficacy of an advertising campaign, and *totally* impossible to quantify the "oomph/power/appeal" of a campaign except by using "increased sales" as a [proxy](http://www.ehow.com/facts_7621616_definition-proxy-measures.html).

I assume the writer means that if you run, say, a newspaper ad campaign, your sales increase will be 10-100 times greater than it would have been if you'd *spent the same amount* sending "spam" emails. Obviously if you run a *properly-targeted* email campaign (only contacting past customers, or people otherwise known to have a particular interest in your product), you'll get much better results. But that costs much more than sending spam.

Answer (score 2):

It means

traditional media campaigns usually have 10-100 times more oomph than ordinary email campaigns.

Comment: ordinary here means new Medea vs traditional?

Comment: *Ordinary* here means with out any special features. i.e. just an email.