# what does "Vanilla experiences" mean?

Tags: idioms

it is clear that "Vanilla" means that component that we add to our food , and no one don't know the meaning of "experiences" but i can't got it in this context , and i thi,k that it is a slang or idiomatic expression , could you help getting the meaning of it :

"
right there in front of them now without
commenting on whether these people were
already very socially awkward in the
first place I thought it was very
interesting how even ***with vanilla
experiences*** one could be so used to
reducing themselves to a voyeur that
they come to prefer that rather than the
real deal  "

Comment: There's not enough to go on, even with that paragraph. However, if I had to guess, I'd say it's "vanilla" in the sense "the basic, plain variant, with nothing unusual or modified". If I have time later I might find a reference and write an answer.

Comment: "vanilla experiences" = simple experiences, trivial experiences.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does vanilla mean in English?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116377/what-does-vanilla-mean-in-english) Which is closed anyway, but there's also [What exactly does this sentence mean: “ … typically 10-100 times that of a plain-vanilla email campaign”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43615/what-exactly-does-this-sentence-mean-typically-10-100-times-that-of-a-pla) and possibly others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Vanilla* is an odd word.

Vanilla is an orchid that grows in Mexico. The tincture (extract in alcohol) of its seed pods has a delicious aroma and flavor.

Its most common use is flavoring ice-cream, so much so that vanilla ice-cream is not just the most popular variety, but effectively the *default* variety: when it comes to ice-cream (and similar products like frozen yogurt) whenever the variety is left unstated, it is assumed to be vanilla.

As a result, *vanilla* came to mean the default variety of anything, and eventually, the boring, unadventurous, predictable variety of anything.

If an automobile is "vanilla", it is a sedan with the base-model engine, and some common color like red or black.  If a person is "vanilla", he is largely conventional and conformist.  The word is often applied to sexual preferences; the opposite being "kinky" or "deviant".

"Vanilla experiences" are whatever the conventional experiences would be in a particular pursuit.